# How to force macOS File Provider Extension to re-enumerate items

Tags: swift, macos, fileprovider-extension

Is there a way to force `macOS File Provider Extension` to re-enumerate items for given parent container?

I am aware that we can `signalEnumerator(for: .workingSet)` but that would just invoke the `enumerateChanges` callback in `FileProviderEnumerator`. What I'm looking for is something like: Internal structure changed so much, that it would be best to re-enumerate the content and rebuild the new model with it. And that should result in invoking the `enumerateItems` callback in the `FileProviderEnumerator`.

Are there any options to achieving just that?

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution to this by calling the `NSFileProviderManager` `reimportItems` function:

```
manager.reimportItems(below: obj, completionHandler: {_ in })
```

Comment: Could you please share how you have handled it in enumerateItems() after triggering, in my case it is actually creating duplicate folder. Not sure how to handle this scenario

Comment: @mixtly87 if possible could you share a implemetation logic to handle this on enumrator side

Comment: @mixtly87 currently, I added a refresh button using info list and when it is clicked I am able to trigger a function for example.
               manager.signalEnumerator(for: itemIdentifiers[0])
I am calling this in the function, however it's only working for workingset and not the other identifiers. My usecase is if I delete a item or add an item on remote server, I want user to be able to click refresh and during that time I want to refresh that specific directory which he clicked refresh on. I am able click refresh and get identifier, however not able to trigger enumerate with signal

Comment: @mixtly87 here is a post exactly matching my question in detail, your help is much appreciated: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76479214/how-to-refresh-specific-directory-in-macos-file-provider-extension

Answer (score 0):

Maybe deregistering and registering FileProvider domain could help.

To remove all domains and add domain again:

```
let identifier = NSFileProviderDomainIdentifier(rawValue: "Your-Domain-Identifier")
let domain = NSFileProviderDomain(identifier: identifier, displayName: "Your-Provider-Domain")

NSFileProviderManager.removeAllDomains { error in
    if error != nil {
        print("Error removing all domains: \(error)")
    } else {
        NSFileProviderManager.add(domain) { error in
            print("Error adding domain: \(error)")
        }
    }
}
```

This should result in re-fetching (enumerating) root container again and all its children as user browses content in Finder.

Comment: Be aware that you will lose all local changes that have not yet been synced to your remote storage when you remove the domain.