# How to Refresh Specific Directory in macOS File Provider Extension

Tags: swift, macos, fileprovider-extension

I'm currently working on a macOS File Provider extension and I've added a refresh button using an info list. Clicking this button triggers a function, as shown:

```
func performAction(identifier actionIdentifier: NSFileProviderExtensionActionIdentifier, onItemsWithIdentifiers itemIdentifiers: [NSFileProviderItemIdentifier], completionHandler: @escaping (Error?) -> Void) -> Progress {
    switch actionIdentifier.rawValue {
    case "Refresh":
        Logger.log.info("[SIGNAL] Signalled Successfully: \(String(describing: itemIdentifiers), privacy: .public)")
        manager.signalEnumerator(for: itemIdentifiers[0]) { error in
            if let error = error {
                Logger.log.info("[SIGNAL] Failed to signal enumerator: \(String(describing: error), privacy: .public)")
            } else {
                Logger.log.info("[SIGNAL] Signalled Successfully: \(String(describing: itemIdentifiers[0]), privacy: .public)")
            }
        }
    default:
        completionHandler(NSError(domain: NSCocoaErrorDomain,
                                  code: NSFeatureUnsupportedError,
                                  userInfo: [NSLocalizedDescriptionKey: "The action is not supported"]))
    }
    return Progress()
}
```

My goal is to refresh a specific directory when the user clicks on the refresh button, for scenarios such as when an item is added or deleted on a remote server. However, currently, I'm able to trigger signalEnumerator(for:) only for the .workingSet and not for other identifiers, even though I'm able to get the identifier of the item that was refreshed.

Here's my enumerator:

```
func enumerator(for containerItemIdentifier: NSFileProviderItemIdentifier, request: NSFileProviderRequest) throws -> NSFileProviderEnumerator {
    return FileProviderEnumerator(enumeratedItemIdentifier: containerItemIdentifier)
}
```

would like to understand why signalEnumerator(for:) is not working for identifiers other than .workingSet and how I can rectify this. Any advice or direction would be much appreciated.

Comment: `signalEnumerator(for:)` only triggers and enumeration if the system holds an active enumerator to the specific directory. If it is a materialized directory and the system has invalidated the original enumerator to it, then changes should be signalled and enumerated via the working set.

Answer (score 0):

Was able to trigger a refresh with reimportItems:

manager.reimportItems(below: iid, completionHandler: {_ in })

Would be interested to find a way to make signalEnumerator work on individual items ( seems to only work on the workingSet )